# How to analytically quantify a chemical's potential to intercalate DNA?

Tags: biochemistry

[This](http://books.google.com/books?id=W9-ggnMUd4QC&pg=PA28&lpg=PA28&dq=polyphenol+dna+intercalate&source=bl&ots=8TWeVCnjIN&sig=KhYbighEgXU46j0e2p1rqZ3KjVM&hl=en&sa=X&ei=fOclVKeGGoruoAT2moGABw&ved=0CDkQ6AEwAg#v=onepage&q=polyphenol%20dna%20intercalate&f=false) shows that polyphenols (like quercetin) have the potential to intercalate DNA, but at potency 100x less than that of ethidium bromide. How does one analytically measure/quantify "100x weaker"?

I'm also interested in how this could apply for the compound [9-fluorenol](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0300483X09003370#) (hydrafinil) - and of the relative potency of 9-fluorenol and quercetin in intercalating DNA.

Comment: Rather than linking to a different site, can you quote your source(s) in the question?

Comment: There are assays to determine binding affinity. I can't remember any references right now, but our lab uses a thiazole orange displacement assay where we bind DNA with thiazole orange, which becomes fluorescent on binding. We titrate in another compound and measure loss of fluorescence as the thiazole is displaced.

Comment: @user137 You should turn that into a proper answer. Looks like you've got the experimental authority on the subject.

Answer (score 2):

Our lab uses a thiazole orange exclusion assay to measure how well our [polyintercalating peptides](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/22786534)* bind DNA. The assay works by mixing thiazole orange with DNA so it becomes fluorescent. Then we measure fluorescence while titrating in peptide and the loss of flourescence indicates binding. This is because thiazole orange is only fluorescent when intercalated into DNA, and as the competing compound displaces it, the free thiazole no longer fluoresces. Note that this assay is not foolproof, polycationic compounds can condense DNA without intercalating, but this conformation change still forces the thiazole out and reduces the fluorescence, so loss of fluorescence implies binding, not necessarily intercalation. This method works for RNA too, but you'll need more thiazole to see signal because there are usually fewer double helices to intercalate into.

Another method is to measure viscosity, because [intercalators](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intercalation_%28biochemistry%29) make the DNA longer and the solution becomes more viscous, but you either need a very sensitive method to measure the change or a very concentrated DNA solution, and the viscosity can probably also be changed by condensing the DNA.

Another possible method MIGHT be [fluorescent anisotropy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fluorescence_anisotropy), if your intercalator is fluorescent. It would spin rapidly outside the DNA, but slow down once it binds the double helix. However, conformational changes in the DNA can change its rotation speed and confound the results.

- *That paper doesn't really mention the assay, it's just to show off the peptides so you understand what I'm talking about a little more. Those peptides also bind by electrostatic interaction and condense DNA, so it's not a pure measurement of intercalation.*